# Python-saving matrix after all iterations

Tags: python, file, numpy, save

by this command i can save result:

```
np.savetxt('Result.txt', phi)
```

, but i want to save this file hundred times. for example i have 100 iteration, with different phi-s, and i want to save hundred files:

```
Result1.txt,
Result2.txt,
.
.
.
Result100.txt.
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of `phi` arrays called `phis`:

```
for i, phi in enumerate(phis, 1):
    np.savetxt('Result{0}.txt'.format(i), phi)
```

or

```
for i, phi in enumerate(phis):
    np.savetxt('Result{0}.txt'.format(i+1), phi)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
np.savetxt('Result1.txt', phis[0])
np.savetxt('Result2.txt', phis[1])
np.savetxt('Result3.txt', phis[2])
np.savetxt('Result4.txt', phis[3])
…
```

and works for any length of `phis`.

Or, if it happens within an iteration:

```
for i in xrange(100):

   # phi = something()

   np.savetxt('Result{0}.txt'.format(i+1), phi)
```

Comment: but i don't have list of phis, i have only one phi and it changes after iterations.

Comment: i think i got it: can i create list of arrays?

Comment: If you have new `phi` in each iteration, then use the last code snippet (works also if you have one `phi` and modify it).

Comment: @AlibekGaliyev  If this answer solved your problem you should [accept it by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to this answer. This will give you both some rep points and also mark this problem as solved.